# Паттерн из шестиугольников с полутонами

Tags: css, css3, html5, вёрстка, svg

Я искал в Google, но не нашёл ответов или статей на этот вопрос.
Я хочу создать сетку из шестиугольников, но она мне нужна в виде полутонов, поэтому мне может понадобиться более одного шестиугольника в шаблоне.

Ниже приведен код, который генерирует шаблон шестиугольников, но не в виде полутонов. Мне нужно, чтобы полутоновый рисунок шел горизонтально.

У меня есть эта [ссылка шаблона](https://stock.adobe.com/nz/images/honeycomb-halftone-vector-abstract-background-halftone-effect-repeating-background-texture/152449673) полутонов от Adobe, но сетка слишком мала, и она идет вертикально, но я хочу его горизонтально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы рисунок шестиугольников проходил горизонтально в виде полутонов?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}
svg {
  background: rgb(125, 155, 132);
}

polygon {
  fill: rgb(125, 155, 132);
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
         <defs>
            <pattern id="hexagons" width="50" height="43.4" 
            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
            patternTransform="scale(2)">
                <polygon 
                points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2" 
                id="hex" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" />
                <use xlink:href="#hex" x="25" />
                <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-25" />
                <use xlink:href="#hex" x="12.5" y="-21.7" />
                <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-12.5" y="-21.7" />
            </pattern>
         </defs>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#hexagons)" />
    </svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [svg hexagon halftone pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56822537/7394871) от участника  [@ONYX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388364/onyx).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56822537/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Вот идея, объединяющая SVG и множественный фон. Хитрость заключается в том, чтобы иметь разные SVG в каждом ряду, где каждый раз, когда вы увеличиваете `stroke`, и затем вы используете некоторый радиальный фон.

Я использовал некоторые переменные CSS, чтобы легко настроить форму:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {  
  height: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  margin: 0;
  --s:9.65vh;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50.1%;
  background: 
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="15" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>');
  background-size:auto var(--s);
  background-position:
    0        calc(0*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(1*var(--p)),
    0        calc(2*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(3*var(--p)),
    0        calc(4*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(5*var(--p)),
    0        calc(6*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(7*var(--p));
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleY(-1);
  transform-origin:bottom;
}
```

Мы можем изменить окраску, изменив цвета SVG:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {  
  height: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  margin: 0;
  --s:9.65vh;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50.1%;
  background: 
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="15" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>');
  background-size:auto var(--s);
  background-position:
    0        calc(0*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(1*var(--p)),
    0        calc(2*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(3*var(--p)),
    0        calc(4*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(5*var(--p)),
    0        calc(6*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(7*var(--p));
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleY(-1);
  transform-origin:bottom;
}
```

А также инвертировать шаблон, изменив `background-position`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {  
  height: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  margin: 0;
  --s:9.65vh;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50.1%;
  background: 
     url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="15" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>');
  background-size:auto var(--s);
  background-position:
    var(--x) calc(7*var(--p)),
    0        calc(6*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(5*var(--p)),
    0        calc(4*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(3*var(--p)),
    0        calc(2*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(1*var(--p)),
    0        calc(0*var(--p));
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleY(-1);
  transform-origin:bottom;
}
```

Для горизонтального шаблона мы делаем то же самое с учетом `repeat-y` и инвертируем почти все значения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {  
  width: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  height:150vh;
  margin:0;
  --s:9.65vw;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:50.1%;
  background: 
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="15" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>');
  background-size:var(--s) auto ;
  background-position:
    calc(7*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(6*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(5*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(4*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(3*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(2*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(1*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(0*var(--p)) 0;
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleX(-1);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

Другой паттерн:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {  
  width: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  height:150vh;
  margin:0;
  --s:9.35vw;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:50.1%;
  background: 
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="15" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>');
  background-size:var(--s) auto ;
  background-position:
    calc(7*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(6*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(5*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(4*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(3*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(2*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(1*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(0*var(--p)) 0;
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleX(-1);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

И еще один пример паттерна - светлый по центру, тёмный по краям:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {  
  width: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  height:150vh;
  margin:0;
  --s:9.35vw;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:50.1%;
  background: 
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="15" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>');
  background-size:var(--s) auto ;
  background-position:
    calc(0*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(1*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(2*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(3*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(4*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(5*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(6*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(7*var(--p)) 0;
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleX(-1);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [svg hexagon halftone pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56824051/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку радиусы шестиугольников являются переменной `y`, вы не можете использовать здесь паттерны.

Основная идея заключается в следующем:

- фон svg белый;
- Шестиугольник закрашен в чёрный цвет `fill="black"`
- Чтобы нарисовать шестиугольники, вам нужно вычислить центр описанного
  круга. Вы делаете это, используя значение радиуса описанной
  окружности R. Это создает гексагональную решетку.
- Внутри гексагональной решетки необходимо изменить радиус описанной
  окружности для шестиугольников в зависимости от `y` следующим
  образом: `let r = R * Math.sin (angle)`, где угол зависит от `y`
  значение  рассчитывается так: `let angle = map (x, 0, H, 0, Math.PI);` Это означает, что `x` принимает значение от `0` до `200` (H), а угол будет иметь значение между `0` и `Math.PI`.

Пожалуйста прочтите комментарии в коде

```js
 const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
// переменные, используемые для рисования шестиугольника
let R = 5;// радиус описанной окружности
let h = R * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3);//половина высоты шестиугольника
let offset = 1.5 * R;//используется для смещения каждой второй строки шестиугольников
let W = 200,H=200;//svg's viewBox = "0 0 200 200"

//нарисовать гексагональную решетку
let i = 0;
for(let y = 0; y<H; y+=h){
i++
let o = (i%2 == 0) ? offset : 0;
for(let x = o; x<W; x+=3*R){
  hex(x,y)
}
}


 // функция, используемая для рисования шестиугольника
 // радиус шестиугольника зависит от значения х
 function hex(x,y) {
    // радиус нарисованного шестиугольника зависит от значения `х`
    let angle = map(x, 0, H, 0, Math.PI);
    let r = R * Math.sin(angle) - .5
   
    let points = ""
    for (var a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
      let o = {}
      o.x = x + r * Math.cos(a * Math.PI / 3);
      o.y = y + r * Math.sin(a * Math.PI / 3);
      points+= `${o.x}, ${o.y} `
    } 
   
     let hexagon = drawSVGelmt({points:points},"polygon", svg)
  }



// функция, используемая для рисования нового элемента SVG
function drawSVGelmt(o,tag, parent) {
  
  let elmt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, tag);
  for (let name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      elmt.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(elmt);
  return elmt;
}


function map(n, a, b, _a, _b) {
  let d = b - a;
  let _d = _b - _a;
  let u = _d / d;
  return _a + n * u;
}
```

```css
svg{background:white; border:1px solid;width:90vh;}
polygon{fill:black}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox = "0 0 200 200" >  
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

Автор вопроса комментирует:

> Это то, что я хочу, но я пытаюсь создать шаблон, чтобы затем
> использовать этот шаблон как маску для изображения.

и позже:

> в основном то, что вы сделали, работает, но мне нужно повторить шаблон
> по всей странице, потому что изображение будет иметь ширину 100% и
> высоту около 800 пикселей

В этом случае вы можете поместить все шестиугольники в группу и использовать clipPath, чтобы обрезать группу следующим образом:

```js
var SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
let H = 800,W=500
var R = 5;
//var l = R;
var h = R * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3);
var offset = 1.5 * R;



let i = 0;
for(let y = 0; y<H; y+=h){
i++
let o = (i%2 == 0) ? offset : 0;
for(let x = o; x<W; x+=3*R){
  hex(x,y)
}
}

 function hex(x,y) {
    let angle = map(x, 0, W, 0, Math.PI);
    let r = R * Math.sin(angle) - .5
   
    let points = ""
    for (var a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
      let o = {}
      o.x = x + r * Math.cos(a * Math.PI / 3);
      o.y = y + r * Math.sin(a * Math.PI / 3);
      points+= `${o.x}, ${o.y} `
    } 
   
     let hexagon = drawSVGelmt({points:points},"polygon", svg)
  }




function drawSVGelmt(o,tag, parent) {
  
  let elmt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, tag);
  for (let name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      elmt.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(elmt);
  return elmt;
}


function map(n, a, b, _a, _b) {
  let d = b - a;
  let _d = _b - _a;
  let u = _d / d;
  return _a + n * u;
}
```

```css
svg{background:white; border:1px solid;}
polygon{fill:black}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 500 800" > 
<clipPath  id="clip">
  <polygon points="250,0 100,100 0 300 100,600 200,800 400,600 500,500 400,200 250,0"/>
</clipPath>
  
<g id="svg" style="clip-path: url(#clip)"></g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [svg hexagon halftone pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823542/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>